# Using std::enable_if to enable a templated constructor and a function that returns another templated instance

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, enable-if

I want to make a templated class, `MyClass<T>`, where I want to have a templated constructor that will take a single argument of type `MyClass<U>`,  that will work only if `U` is derived from `T` (or the same as `T`, essentially also acting as a copy constructor in that case).  If it is not, I want to fail at compile time.  Also, it will have a second templated member function, `MyClass<U> convert<U>() const` that only works if `U` is derived from `T` (or the same as `T`).  The actual implementation of these functions is not important at this time, right now I am just trying to figure out how to declare them.

Although in some cases, it would be possible to use a `static_assert` with just `std::is_base_of` without `std::enable_if` to make the compile fail, but I'm wondering if I can achieve something slightly more robust using std::enable_if.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So what is the question?  Generally `enable_if` is the thing you use to constrain a template.  Have you tied it and it does not work?

Comment: First make sure you understand the difference between a static assert and a constrained template. The former causes hard errors, the latter makes your constructor detectable. That is, the question `is_constructible<MyClass<T>, Args...>` has different answers, and you need to decide first which behaviour you want.

Comment: I've been trying to generalize from examples I've found in the 4th edition of Stroustrup's C++ Programming Language, but haven't had any luck.... I've tried several permutations that I could think of, using `std::is_base_of<T,U>` and `std::enable_if`, but nothing I've tried so far has worked.  I'm using gcc 5.3, and compiling with -std=c++11, so I should have the C++11 functionality available.

Answer (score 0):

### Templated Constructor in class template with different template parameters

You will run into the first issue to consider here.
As you can not explicitly specific the template argument for the constructor, it has to be deduced from the argument itself.

I tried around myself for a while now as I was curious and obviously the subsequent code can't work:

```
class A {
    public:
        inline static std::string print() { return "A"; }    
};

class B 
    : public A {
    public:
        // Consciously hidden parent "print()"
        inline static std::string print() { return "B"; }
};

template <typename T>
class MyClass {
    public:

    explicit MyClass() {
        std::cout << "Default of MyClass with " << T::print() << std::endl;
    }

    template <typename U>
    MyClass(const typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<T, typename 
U::internal_type>::value, U>::type& other) {
        std::cout << "Copy constructor of equal or derived type!" << 
U::internal_type::print() << std::endl;
    }

    typedef T internal_type;
};

int main()
{ 
    MyClass<A> a;
    MyClass<B> b;
    MyClass<A> cpa(a);
    MyClass<A> cpb(b); // Error
}
```

The important part is this:

```
template <typename U>
    MyClass(const typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<T, typename U::internal_type>::value, U>::type& other) {
        std::cout << "Copy constructor of equal or derived type!" << 
U::internal_type::print() << std::endl;
    }
```

I defined the internal_type helper to perform the check on the MyClass-template parameter of the *MyClass with T = B* parameter, and here comes the problem:

Usually, we provide the U from the outside and do not do some enable_if magic without it.
In this case, we pass in MyClass without any information what U is, but try to derive information from U...

This is at least how I understood it right now from trying around.

If it worked, the portion:

```
std::is_base_of<T, typename U::internal_type>::value
```

would be substituted in our case to

```
std::is_base_of<A, B>::value
```

which should give true. 
Enable if in turn should then take the "U", which is MyClass and substitute the entire thing with it, equivalent to:

```
MyClass<A> {
    //...
    MyClass(const MyClass<B>& other) {
    }
};
```

So I think at least the constructor is not possible as you wish.

Please Template Meta Programming Master correct me if I'm wrong and need to learn some more :D